# MSUnit Assert not Working

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Everything is working on MSUnit except my Assert, I checked and found that it's a bit different in MSUnit than nUnit, went through a blog post and doing exactly same but still getting error while debugging the test.

When I check my ex in the Unit Test (after throwing the error), the message I get is "error in the application", which fails the test as the expected message is different

Any Ideas?

```
[TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidAreaException))]
    public void GetAreaWithNegativeValueTest()
    {
        try
        {
            Utility.GetArea(2, -1, 2);

        }
        catch (InvalidAreaException ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual ("Inputs must be positive numbers", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }

//Exception Class   
        public class InvalidAreaException : ApplicationException, ISerializable
    {
    public  string msg;

    public InvalidAreaException(string message)
    {
        //msg = message;
    }
 }

//Actual Method to be tested
public static double GetArea(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)

    {
        double area = 0d;

        if ((arg1 < 0) || (arg2 < 0) || (arg3 < 0))
        {
            throw new InvalidAreaException("Inputs must be positive numbers");
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Your GetArea method doesn't have a return statement, does this even compile?

Comment: it is not called MSUnit it is called MSTests framework, anyway try to remove the try/catch from the method: "GetAreaWithNegativeValueTest" because you want the method to detect the exception right?

Comment: I'd review your unit test.  A good test should have only one path through the code (otherwise you risk logic issue within a test itself).  Doing this will likely point to your issue.

Comment: While pasting the code, I missed the return statement, thanks for pointing, I'm using the following post as they told that in MsTests, Asserts are testing differently.
http://imistaken.blogspot.com.au/2008/09/mstest-expectedexception-and-exception.html?m=1
Do I need to write anything in my Exception Class

Comment: @sam you forgot to populate your Message property(see my answer...), about your link, i know lior friedman since 2013 and he is an expert in his domain, i never read his blog but, i believe, it is a very good resource... so i recommend you to read his articles. one more thing, if you decide to test exceptions. do it at the end of your process. focus on what my method should do(for example calculate area) instead of "if i pass... then.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the C'tor of InvalidAreaException to: and then your test will pass

```
    public class InvalidAreaException : ApplicationException, ISerializable
    {

        public InvalidAreaException(string message):base(message)
        {
        }
    }
```

your assert is against Message property which is property of the base class, and you forgot to populate this property